# what is `this` in sinon.test() in mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

My codes:

```
it('should', sinon.test(function() {
  console.log(this); // what `this` refer here?
  ...
}));
```

In the above code, **what `this` refer in the `sinon.test()` function?**

I tried to log it, but got the error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Sinon version: 1.17.6

Any comments welcomed. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

after reading the below answer, I am still confused. Why the following two pieces of codes work when `this.myOnject.log` was stubbed only once?

```
  it('should', sinon.test(function() {
    const stubLog = this.stub(this.myObject.log, 'warn');
    // ...
    this.myObject.process();
    // expect codes...
  }));


  it('should', sinon.test(function() {
    const stubLog = sinon.stub(this.myObject.log, 'warn');
    // ...
    this.myObject.process();
    // expect codes...
  }));
```

**UPDATE**

**If downvoted, please leave some comments to let me know why you downvoted. I am very confused by the question I posted. But I am more confused why so many people downvoted, but did not leave any useful comments.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sinon.test` creates a new [Sinon sandbox](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/sandbox/) for your test and **augments** the normal `this` object that Mocha passes to your test with Sinon-specific methods like `spy`, `stub`, etc. that call the corresponding methods on the sandbox that is automatically created. The fact that it augments the object allows you to still use all the stock Mocha methods that Mocha normally provides on `this`, and allows you to set values on arbitrary fields. The `restore` method of the sandbox is automatically called when the test ends. It is a convenient way to provide isolation between tests so that modifications to common objects that one test performs through Sinon don't affect other tests.

Here's an example:

```
const sinon = require("sinon");

before(function () {
    // We set "moo".
    this.moo = "I'm a cow.";
});

it("test", sinon.test(function () {
    // We can access "stock" Mocha functions.
    this.timeout(0);

    // However, this is augmented with sinon functions.
    const spy = this.spy();
    spy();

    // We can access "moo";
    console.log("value of moo", this.moo);
}));
```

This produces:

```
value of moo I'm a cow.
  ✓ test

  1 passing (34ms)
```

The code above assumes Sinon 1.x. In Sinon 2.x and over `sinon.test` is no longer bundled with Sinon but is its own separate [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-test).

Comment: Thanks. what are the differences between `sinon.stub()` and `this.stub()` in the `sinon.test()`?

Comment: The difference is that `this.stub()` in `sinon.test()` uses the sandbox. If you just call `sinon.stub()` you do not benefit from the sanbox and then you have to perform any necessary cleanup yourself.